# orderBy-querybuilder and pagination in laravel 5

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to make an orderBy in my query and a pagination for the items from a gallery, but instead of sort the complete query, laravel order only page-by-page content, so if I order desc it only works 1 page, when I go to the next page I can find values really different (ordered, but without relationship with the first page).

Here is my query:

```
    $product = DB::table("product")
        ->leftJoin("provider","product.provider_id","=","provider.id")
        ->orderBy("daily_sales","DESC")
        ->select('product.*','provider.comercial_name')
        ->paginate(6);
```

Comment: it is because paginate function uses limit and offset

Comment: Please provide some sample data with the expected and actual results.

Comment: Read the documentation on this here https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results if you are using relationships you may try [package for sorting](https://github.com/Kyslik/column-sortable).

Comment: what values you found are different?

Comment: in my first page I got values orderes from 88 to 60, but en the 2nd page i've got values from 160 to 120

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$product = DB::table("product")
        ->leftJoin("provider","product.provider_id","=","provider.id")
        ->select('product.*','provider.comercial_name')
        ->orderBy("daily_sales","DESC") 
        ->paginate(6);
```